# C# Crash not caught by Debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, crash, exit-code

I have a pretty large project that just recently started crashing on exit. I am not the greatest C# coder but everything generally works as intended. In this case however, when I close my console application, it crashes but is not caught by the MSVC Debugger.

1) When I build it in Release and run it, it generally always crashes when I exit.

2) When I build it in Debug and run it, it seems to only crash on exit every 1 out of 3-5 times.

I did manage to get the error though when it didn't exit properly, but unfortunately the Exit Code doesn't match anything I can find online.

```
The program '[11108] MCDaemon.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

From what I have read on other people's questions, this is generally caused by Unmanaged Code acting up. Is there any way I can actually find out what the issue is short of a massive amounts of debug lines?

*EDIT*

From an answer below, this is the code causing the Exit code, but I don't really see anything issue with it.

```
public static Boolean Handler(MyWin32.CtrlTypes CtrlType)
{
    // A switch to handle the event type.
    switch (CtrlType)
    {
        case MyWin32.CtrlTypes.CTRL_C_EVENT:
            Program.TerminateProcess();
            break;
        case MyWin32.CtrlTypes.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
            Program.TerminateProcess();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void TerminateProcess()
{
    // Stop the Poll Timer from Running
    PollTimer.Stop();

    log.LogMessage("Process is being Shutdown.");
    log.LogMessage("Requesting Process to Stop....");
    SendProcessCmd("stop");

    // Wait and make sure it has exited
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    if (!myProcess.HasExited)
    {
        log.LogMessage("My Process did not stop on its own, forcing Process to quit.");
        myProcess.Kill();
    }

    log.LogMessage("My Process has been Shutdown.");
}
```

Comment: Have you attached to the AppDomain.UnhandledException event and seeing what the problem might be? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I have had that code in there for a while, so was kind of confused it didn't pickup a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Wait and make sure it has exited
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

That's the problem statement.  You are pinvoking [SetConsoleCtrlHandler()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683242.aspx) in your code to get your Handler method called.  Windows requires the control handler to be responsive and not take too long to return from the callback.  The timeout for the CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT is *exactly* 5 seconds, explaining why it sometimes works.  If it takes longer then Windows pulls the plug on the process.

You'll need to implement TerminateProcess differently.  Killing a process is fairly arbitrary, you ought to be better off just not doing this.  Or start another guard process. I can't make that call though.

Comment: You were right on the money, as this does appear to be where the source of the issue is. I don't really understand why running it in Debug mode doesn't suffer from the crash on close, but running in Release does. I did manage to get it to finally give me a crash error though. Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.WaitForThreadExit() + 0x96 bytes

Comment: Well I figured it out. My Release build was for x86 (due to a bug in one of the APIs I am using, this is required) and my Debug build was ANY CPU. I have no idea why the former would cause it to crash though :/

Comment: Hmm, no, you haven't fixed it.  Change the Sleep() argument to 6000 to make it consistent.  These kind of rude aborts are never not a problem.  Make your program exit nicely by detecting a keystroke like Escape.

Comment: No, I meant you were right about the 5 seconds part, but it was crashing even when I changed it to less time than that, so I had 2 problems. I managed to resolve that issue as well by changing the build target to ANY CPU (no idea why this was causing issues at x86).

Answer (score 1):

0xC000013A: The application terminated as a result of a Ctrl+C.

This is because you closed the console window, and the application wasn't expecting you to, so Windows terminated it for you.

Sorry, but I don't know how to catch a console window close event in managed code.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. I updated my original question and included the code for my handler for the Ctrl+C event, which I don't really see any issue with.

Comment: @Brett: Are you sure that your handler is being called?